# Can Alerts Have Buttons On Them That Load External Content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use jquery to make an alert that has buttons on it and when the buttons are clicked the one that wasn't clicked wont load its content but the other will is this possible?

Comment: With `alert`? Nope. With an interface you build yourself? Sure

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: Well Rip, I'll just have to do it with regular buttons

Comment: Ok That will work thanks Phil!